# upload pdf and image files using retrofit in android using java?

Tags: java, android, api, rest, retrofit

I am facing in android studio when i am upload image to the server its upload successfully but when i am select a pdf file and upload to the server the App will be crashed? How could i upload a pdf file to the server?

```
       //    @POST("User/UploadFiles?patientID=28609")
           @Multipart
           @POST("User/UploadFiles")
           Call<ResponseBody> uploadFile(@Query("patientID") int patientID,
                                         @Part MultipartBody.Part file);
```

This is my Code.

```
       package com.maxvecare.itocean.pk.usersactivities;

import static com.maxvecare.itocean.pk.usersactivities.DoctorsActivity.TAG;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.maxvecare.itocean.pk.R;
import com.maxvecare.itocean.pk.apisutilities.ApiInterface;
import com.maxvecare.itocean.pk.apisutilities.ApiUtilities;
import com.maxvecare.itocean.pk.useradapters.DocumentAdapter;
import com.maxvecare.itocean.pk.usermodels.DocumentsClass;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class UploadClinicReports extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mChooseFileBtn, mSaveFileBtn;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<DocumentsClass> documentsClassList;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    DocumentAdapter documentAdapter;
    private ProgressDialog mProgress;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    // this is the action code we use in our intent,
    // this way we know we're looking at the response from our own action
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath;
    ImageView imageView;
    private static final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1234;
    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
    private Uri filePath;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    TextView tv;
    int patientID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_clinic_reports);

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("doctorApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
        patientID = sharedPreferences.getInt("patientID", 0);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Pat"+patientID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.m_Toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Upload Documents");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.back_button);
        mChooseFileBtn = findViewById(R.id.uploadBtn);
        mSaveFileBtn = findViewById(R.id.SaveBtn);
        tv = findViewById(R.id.showDocs);
        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imagefile);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(UploadClinicReports.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewSaveDocs);
        documentsClassList = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mChooseFileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(UploadClinicReports.this);
                alertDialog.setTitle("Clinic Report");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Upload Your Clinic Report");
                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Image Pick", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // select image file
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                    }
                });
                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Pdf Pick", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // select a file
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("application/pdf");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
        mSaveFileBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (filePath != null) {
                    uploadImage();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(UploadClinicReports.this, "Please Select a File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            filePath = data.getData();
        }
    }

    private String getPath(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        String document_id = cursor.getString(0);
        document_id = document_id.substring(document_id.lastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?", new String[]{document_id}, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        @SuppressLint("Range") String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));
        cursor.close();
        return path;// da se di
    }

    private void uploadImage() {
        mProgress.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgress.show();
        String path = getPath(filePath);
        try {
            String uploadId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
            File imageFile = new File(path);                                                          // Create a file using the absolute path of the image
            RequestBody reqBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), imageFile);
            MultipartBody.Part partImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", imageFile.getName(), reqBody);
            Call<ResponseBody> upload = ApiUtilities.getService().uploadFile(patientID, partImage);
            upload.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(UploadClinicReports.this, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
                    } else {
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(UploadClinicReports.this, "Failed" + response.code(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + response);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                    mProgress.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(UploadClinicReports.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
    **How could I upload a pdf file? I am struggling to get the absolute path of pdf file from URI.
```

I am facing the following issue when i am upload pdf file to the server in android studio java Using retrofit.**

Comment: Please tell how your code works. I see an image view and a bitmap. They are not needed to upload an image file. Further the code to upload an image file should be the same for uploading a pdf file or any other file. You only need one function to upload a file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i am uploading image to the server it upload successfully but i am uploading pdf then it will not uploaded the app will crashed? How to upload pdf file to the server using the same code. Please provide usefull code.@blackapps

Comment: How to upload pdf file to the server using same code?@Community

Comment: My god... you only repeat yourself and are not reacting on comments. Read them again and write a better post.  `You only need one function to upload a file.` The type of file does/should not matter. Just upload the bytes of the file. Not more. Not less. Dont mess around with the bytes of the file.

Comment: So what i am doing plz solve them? I am not understand more? My Question is that How to Upload image or pdf file to the server in android.@blackapps

Comment: Plz Solve that problem How to Upload image or pdf to the server?@blackapps